# Why is the ng-class directive being compiled after my custom directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Link to plnkr for example explained below: http://plnkr.co/edit/oYvwHnAIvFb4rUqqwsz3?p=preview

Hi, I dont understand why angular is compiling my code this way and need some help understanding why it is doing so. I have an outer directive which doing an ng-repeat on and array and creating a new directive for each item in the array. Wrapping around this inner directive is a div which has an ng-class attached to it.

The issue I'm running into is that I want the ng-class to be applied to the wrapping div before the directive's link function is called, but this isn't the case. The controller and link function of all of the nested directives are compiled before any of the wrapping ng-class functions are called. You can see an example of what time talking about in the plnkr I've linked above (check the console to see the order in which things are getting printed). The print order I want it to be is the following:

```
adding class to inner directive  1
Inner - Controller undefined
Inner - Link 1
adding class to inner directive  2
Inner - Controller undefined
Inner - Link 2
Inner - Controller undefined
...
```

Any help on understanding this / getting it to compile in the order i need would be great.

relevant code:
html

```
<div bn-outer>
      <div ng-repeat="a in arr">
        <div  ng-class="classFunction(a)">
          <span bn-inner ng-model="model" ng-init="model=a">

            directive: {{a}}

          </span>  
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

angular

```
    // Create an application module for our demo.
    var app = angular.module( "Demo", [] );

    app.directive(
        "bnOuter",
        function() {
            function Controller( $scope ) {
                console.log( "Outer - Controller" );
                $scope.arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
                $scope.classFunction = function(int){
                  console.log("adding class to inner directive ", int);
                };
            }
            function link( $scope, element, attributes, controller ) {
                console.log( "Outer - Link" );
            }
            // Return directive configuration.
            return({
                controller: Controller,
                link: link
            });
        }
    );

    app.directive(
        "bnInner",
        function() {
            function Controller( $scope ) {
                console.log( "Inner - Controller", $scope.model );
            }
            function link( $scope, element, attributes, controller ) {
                console.log( "Inner - Link", $scope.model );
            }
            // Return directive configuration.
            return({
                controller: Controller,
                link: link
            });
        }
    );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post relevant code in the question as well.

Comment: Calling the ngclass expression is different from compiling ng-class directive. You are not comparing apple to apple. ng-class expression is evaluated during the [first watch execution](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngClass.js#L11) which happens during the digest cycle after the directives are compiled. If you were to put a console.log inside the ng-class link function you will be able to note the consistency.

Comment: `I want the ng-class to be applied to the wrapping div before the directive's link function is called` --> Why do you need such tight coupling for a directive to be compiled?  Instead if you are looking to perform an operation in that directive after all the directives have been compiled, bound and rendered, you could defer it with a `$timeout` by pushing that into the async queue. It will make sure that piece of code is run after the first digest cycle that runs after the directives are compiled.

Comment: This makes sense and I understand the issue now. I'm probably gonna have to rewrite some of my directives to do some decoupling. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An excellent explanation on this topic can be found here

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2810-directive-architecture-template-urls-and-linking-order-in-angularjs.htm

And this

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx

Basically it sounds you need to play with the 'pre-link' function